# C++: Convenient way to access operator[] from within class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a C++ class that overloads `operator[]`, the array subscript/brackets operator.  This is awfully convenient outside of my class, where I can write `foo[bar`].  However, I can't figure out how to use this notation when I'm implementing methods *inside* my class.

I know I can write `operator[](bar)` or `this->operator[](bar)` but those are fairly unwieldy and take away a lot of the convenience of the operator in the first place.  (I also know I can just add a new method that calls the operator.)  Is there a way I can write `this[bar]` or `this->[bar]` or something similarly nice?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
(*this)[bar];
```

works fine for me.

Comment: @TanishqBanyal mostly the answer is "because it doesn't work" :-).

Most specifically, it's because the return type of `operator->` is a POINTER. You could do this...

`this->operator[](bar]` but that's hideous. (example: https://godbolt.org/z/n4K7W9Yd3)

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
(*this)[bar]
```

to call the `operator[]` of the instance object.

Assuming `bar` is an integer (or can be auto-converted to one), `this[bar]` treats the `this` pointer as an array and indexes the `bar`-th element of that array. Unless `this` is in an array, this will result in undefined behavior. If `bar` isn't integer-like, expect a compile-time error.

Comment: An overload to `operator[]` may accept things other than integral types as arguments, so it may not compile at all let alone go to the `bar`-th element of that "array".

Comment: @user904963 good points. I've updated the last paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

I use a at() function, and have the operator[] call the at() function behind the scenes, so operator[] is just syntactic sugar. That's how std::vector does it, so it seems like a reasonable (with precedence) way to do it.

Now for a complete syntactic sugar hack (can't say I fully recommend it but might strike your fancy):

```
class Widget
{
    Widget&     self;
public:
    Widget() :self(*this)
    {}

    void operator[](int)
    {
        printf("hello");
    }

    void test()
    {
        //scripting like sugar
        //you pay the price of an extra reference per class though
        self[1]; 
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Widget w;
    w[1];
    w.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Also if you want to do this for free, without paying the cost of the reference, **AND** are a follower of some evil sect dedicated to making programmers suffer you could do:

```
#define self (*this)
```

Actually I think that's how most handles are implemented in Apple's NS API...

Comment: I do like this, in a sense, because the way I've been doing it for the past few minutes has been setting self = *this and then using self.  Thanks.

Comment: Vector is the other way around, because vector::at() has to do range checking before calling operator[]()

Comment: Word of caution with the `Widget& self` version: If you still want to be able to copy your class, use `operator=`, etc., you will have to write a lot of additional new boilerplate.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to `(*this)[bar]` is to use a named member function that does the work of `operator[]`.  Overloaded operators make things easier on your users.  More importantly, they are part of your class' **interface**.  Ask yourself if it really makes sense to implement your class in terms of its own public interface.  If not, I suggest writing a separate (protected or private) member function to do the work, and then have `operator[]` and any other function call it.

Answer (score 2):

```
 operator[](bar)
```

This should work too. It works for me!

Comment: In my question, that is the very first option I mention.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **(*this)[bar]**, but that might not be much of an improvement...