# Overload operator [ ] to return the integer at subscript location.If values of wrong data type passed as index ,handle by exception using c++

Tags: c++, arrays, exception, operator-overloading, try-catch

if index value is integer then it will return the corresponding value. if index value is float then it will throw an error which will be handled by exception such that values of wrong data type do not get passed as index; and if passed it will get handled by exception.
When I access A[f] it should be handled by exception, But it shows compile time error (invalid types char[10[float] array subscript)

```
class Vector {
    char A[10];

public:
    char operator[](int i)
    {
        return A[i];
    }
    float operator[](float i)
    {
        throw i;
    }
    void get()
    {
        ..
    } //To get the string input
    void Display()
    {
        float f = 1.0;
        cout << A[f];
    };
    int main()
    { //Vector v;
        try {
            v.Display(); //What should I change in this code
        }
        catch (float i) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you were expecting the class `Vector::operator []` to somehow override the native array `operator[]` for non `Vector` objects, that's not going to work. This error message is crystal clear. `A` (a array of  `char`) cannot be indexed by `float`.

Comment: If you want to call your own operator, you need `(*this)[f]` or `this->operator[](f)`

Comment: When you are accessing a variable from inside the parent class, it does not call the [] operator. Those operators you have defined are for the class vector, not the char array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++: Convenient way to access operator\[\] from within class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605037/c-convenient-way-to-access-operator-from-within-class)

Comment: I got it now. Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that does what I think you're trying to do.

Note that if you want the operator[] functions to be called the you need to use [] on an **object of the type of the class**, not on a normal array.    I've added another line to your main function to show how to use [] on the Vector object.

If you do want to use [] on the class object from a function inside the class then you need to use (*this)[].

```
class Vector {
    char A[10];
public:
    char operator [](int i)
    {
        return A[i];
    }
    float operator [](float i)
    {
        throw i;
    }
    void get()
    {

    }//To get the string input
    void Display()
    {
        float f = 1.0;
        cout << (*this)[f];
    };
    
};

int main()
{
    Vector v;
    try {
        v.Display();// Throws an exception
        v[1.0f];   //  This is how you call the operator[] functions. 
    }
    catch (float i) {
        cout << "exception" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << A[f];
```

`A` is a `char` array, and its `[]` operator cannot take a floating point index, of course.

You obviously meant to invoke this class's ***`operator[]` overload*** which has nothing directly to do with the array, whatsoever:

```
cout << (*this)[f];
```